# Is it possible to see exact time of commit in gitextensions?

Tags: git-extensions

I would like to have both relative time and exact date and time visible for each commit in gitextensions.

Is this possible? Is there an option for editing visible columns?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For just the exact date (no relative date) you can turn off "Show relative date instead of full date."

1. Go to `Tools|Settings`
2. Choose `Appearance` on the left
3. Un-tick `Show relative date instead of full date`

[image: Screenshot of GitExtensions settings, showing Show relative date instead of full date.]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You can add a feature request for that.
https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/new

Comment: I'm working with version 2.50.02 and I can confirm that it is possible, see answer of Tom Leys.

Comment: The question was if it is possible seeing both: relative and full date.